# how to prevent overfitting

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

i'm doing for my final project and i'm new in ConVnets. i want to classifies which one is genuine image and spoof image. i have +-8000 data (combine). and i want to show you some of my training log.

```
Epoch 7/100
311/311 [==============================] - 20s 63ms/step - loss: 0.3274 - accuracy: 0.8675 - val_loss: 0.2481 - val_accuracy: 0.9002
Epoch 8/100
311/311 [==============================] - 20s 63ms/step - loss: 0.3189 - accuracy: 0.8691 - val_loss: 0.3015 - val_accuracy: 0.8684
Epoch 9/100
311/311 [==============================] - 19s 62ms/step - loss: 0.3201 - accuracy: 0.8667 - val_loss: 0.2460 - val_accuracy: 0.9036
Epoch 10/100
311/311 [==============================] - 19s 62ms/step - loss: 0.3063 - accuracy: 0.8723 - val_loss: 0.2752 - val_accuracy: 0.8901
Epoch 11/100
311/311 [==============================] - 19s 62ms/step - loss: 0.3086 - accuracy: 0.8749 - val_loss: 0.2717 - val_accuracy: 0.8988
[INFO] evaluating network...
```

```
model = Sequential()
inputShape = (height, width, depth)
chanDim = -1

if K.image_data_format() == "channels_first":
    inputShape = (depth, height, width)
    chanDim = 1

model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding="same", input_shape=inputShape))   model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), padding="same"))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=chanDim))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dropout(0.6))

model.add(Dense(classes))
model.add(Activation("softmax"))
```

the input is 32x32 and it has two classes. i used `EarlyStopping` in keras to prevent overfitting. and i always change the value of learning rate and try to change the number of neuron node but still the training always stop below 20 epoch. any advice to prevent overfitting ? since i'm beginner in convolutional neural network. Thanks in advance !

**PS** LR: 0.001 BS: 20 EPOCHS: 100

Comment: I would suggest to use k-fold cross-validation for this purpose.

Comment: thank you for your comment, i'll try that

Comment: It looks like you have a decent amount of dropout already, and your val_loss and val_accuracy seem to be doing better overall. You probably don't need early stopping. If you're allowed to add in some more transforms / data augmentation, that could help. You could also use weight decay if you're really concerned, and you can never go wrong with k-fold cross validation, as Christoph suggested

Comment: yes, actually  without early stopping my val_loss is doing ok above 20 epochs. but i'm just afraid if i train with large number of epochs it would lead to overfitting. @bug_spray